# How to play 4-player in Red Faction 2 for PS4?

Tags: ps4, controllers, red-faction-2

Recently bought Red Faction 2 on PS Store, hooked up 4 pads (all logged in as unique users) but when trying to play multiplayer, it gives an error saying no controllers match the specified players. It works fine for 1 or 2 players but not more.

It even states on the overview in the PS Store:

> 1 - 4 players

**How can my buddies and I get this to work?**

Comment: Whats the specific error code, I cannot make a clear idea of what is going on without it. Hint: its the something like this XX-12345678 (1-2 letters, amount of numbers will vary with some ending in -00, replacing 00 with other numbers)

Comment: @KingsleyZhong, unfortunately there is no error code. It just says "ERROR"...

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a proper answer, but I think you can't play with 4 controllers.

You don't appear to be the first person to experience this, as people on these two sites have experienced something similar:

http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Gaming-Network-Support/Red-Faction-2-4-Player-Split-Screen-Issue/td-p/25329609

http://forum.nordicgames.at/threads/244676-Red-faction-2-on-playstation-4-4-players-issue

Side note: You can ask for a refund if you want, as you bought it for 4-players gameplay, which is unavailable.

Comment: Those look like random forums, so I wouldn't rely too much on them staying available forever. Here are archive links:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180221085151/http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Gaming-Network-Support/Red-Faction-2-4-Player-Split-Screen-Issue/td-p/25329609
https://web.archive.org/web/20180221085201/http://forum.nordicgames.at/threads/244676-Red-faction-2-on-playstation-4-4-players-issue
(You don't have to do anything, the answer is fine as it is.)

Comment: Thanks, I read those posts too but was hoping there might be a method to register the controllers correctly...

Comment: Chances are that it just doesn't work with 4 controllers

Comment: I'm going to try filing a support ticket to see what they say... they may have a solution but if not just ask for a refund.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong, let us know how you get on please :-)